# Solving for linearly independent vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $\{u, v\}$ is a linearly independent set and $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix over $\mathbb R$.

Suppose also that $(A-\lambda I)v=u$, where $Au=\lambda u$.

(I derived this information from the following fact: $y(x)=xe^{\lambda x}u+e^{\lambda x}v$ satisfies the differential equation $Ay(x)=y'(x)$.)

I am asked to show that I can solve for $v$ in this situation. But I am not sure how to do so. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Notice that $y$ is a fairly nice function of $x$, so you know how to differentiate it, and then write out $Ay = y'$ in terms of a vector equation, see what that gives. That would be a good start

Comment: @mdave16 I'm interested in knowing how the linear independence comes into play.

Comment: Where have you got to? Show some more working. I think it's fairly obvious, but to spell it out would be to negate the exercise in making sure you understand. @CuriousKid7

Comment: @mdave16 At one point in my derivation I got that $(\lambda v -Av +u)+t(\lambda u-Au)=0$, which is how I got the equations I said to assume above. But I still can't see how the linear independence guarantees the ability to solve for $v$.

Comment: How much do you know about Jordan Chains/Blocks?

Comment: @mdave16 I know the basics. But my idea is that we should be able to somehow choose $u$ and then scale $v$ appropriately. But I can't figure out how to explicitly do this.

Comment: But also, only using $Av = u + \lambda v$ and $Au = \lambda u$. Assume $v = \mu u$ for some $\mu \in \mathbb{K}$ (the field you work over). As two vectors, this is what it would mean for $u,v$ to be linearly dependent. Now $Av = A \mu u = u + \lambda \mu u$ from the first equation and $A \mu u = \mu A u = \mu\lambda u$ from the latter. Hence $u = 0$ which is sorta uncool.

Comment: @mdave16 I know that they can't be linearly dependent. But I am asking how knowing they are in fact linearly independent allows us to solve for $v$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59952/discussion-between-mdave16-and-curiouskid7).